# How to access shared drives of Parent Network

Tags: wireless-router, routing

I have a wired network set to static IPs. I have introduced a new wifi router to one of the wire and assigned one of the static IP to the router. Now few persons are directly connected to the wired network and rest of the people are connected to wifi router with the IPs assigned by the wifi router.

How it is possible to share both the networks? I want to access wired network shared drives from the machines connected to the wifi router or vice versa.

Any help? thanks.

Comment: So as I understand it. You have a switch connected to several computers with static IP's. You have connected a wireless router(Or is it a switch??) to this existing switch(Router?). Using the correct terminology here is important as depending on the kind of hardware you have the solutions you get will differ.

Comment: @VBwhatnow see reply to answer 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have separate networks on LAN and WIFI, you need to setup routing between the two (and firewall rules if you have a firewall installed on the router).

depending on what os  you have, the route add rule will look a bit different, but, let say you have the two network 192.168.0.0/24 for you LAN and 192.168.1.0/24 for your WLAN.

then on a host on the WLAN add this statement

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

and on the LAN host add this statement

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```

if you give more information on your network, your host type, and wifirouter, we can give more specific help.. this is very generic, since lack of info.

Comment: I am using iBall Baton 150M Wireless N router and my OS is Windows. I am not very good in networking. We have a set of LAN wires coming from a local server (say building server). These wires have static IPs, but as the crowd increased in my company, I have a installed a router and connected it with one of the static IP. Now in our network few computers are directly connected by wires while rest are connected through wifi router. We are facing problems in sharing files as of now we have two difrnt networks. Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be easier to put your wifi router in bridge mode. If you do this, the nodes/computers connected to the wifi will still be in the same network as the wired ones and you avoid the problem alltogether.

Comment: Please explain your answer for future visitors

Comment: thank you @RohitGupta, I added some more lines