# Access NAS in parent network

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, nas

I tried to draw a diagram of my home network in paint:
[image: diagram]

As you can see the NAS (Lenovo IX2), my pc and our access point/router (Linksys EA6400) are connected by cable to the box/router from our provider. Our other pc's, phones and our smart TV are connected to that access point with Wifi.

I can access the NAS from my pc, but the devices connected to the access point can't. I found [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/783299/how-to-access-shared-drives-of-parent-network) but I don't understand that answer (What is and where do I put a "routing rule"?)

It's not really possible to move any of those devices and running cables is going to be difficult, so ideally I'm looking for a non-hardware solution.

How do I make the NAS, or any device on the parent network, visible to devices connected to a child router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you connect the box to the WAN port of the Linksys? If so, try to connect the box to a switch port on the Lynksys. You should deactivate the DHCP server on the Linksys too.